# What parts of Autorun need to be disabled to avoid Autosave lag in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3, technical-issues

I've read that disabling Autosave in Skyrim helps to avoid the lag it can create after the savefile has exceeded a certain threshold.  However, I'm wondering if it really is *all* of Autosave that needs to be disabled, or just some parts?

On the PS3, Autosave options are:

- Save on Rest
- Save on Wait
- Save on Travel
- Save on Character Menu [Choose Interval]

Are some of these options still fairly useable without undue lag, or do all of them need to be shut off?  Autosave has saved my hide a fair number of times, so I hesitate to disable it entirely.  Has anyone tested just shutting off bits and pieces?

Comment: Adding a check-mark to "Save on Wait", it seems.  And, since "Rest" seems so close in its functional operation to "Wait" (and since I rarely use "Rest") I think I'll kill that one too.  I've also disabled "Save on Travel" since I guessed that would be perhaps the most error-prone.  I hope "Save on Character Menu" can survive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to take them all off becaus the lag will turn in to a complete freze as the file gets bigger.( that is what is now going on with my game, only time it don't freze is if I am in a dungon dining the saving myself.) also the auto save do not overwrite other auto saves, so by turning it off will save you a ton of room on your HD.
Good luck hope they fix this for us soon :)

Comment: @ chris, the game save every save as if it was a completely different charitor. Sense your save are not simply updated, it ends up being a bigger and bigger save file that is its own. So if u where to delete ever save besides that last time u saved it would still be bigger the be t time you where to save. I hope this makes sense. In other words a save is stand alone.  Even if u only killed one npc sense the last time you saved

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences with a 10mb save file it is the autosave on character menu which is the worst offender because it is the most frequent.

In saying this, I find it interesting that this is recommended as a way to prevent the lag. My understanding was the save file size is relative to how much has changed in the world, not how much has changed since the last save.

If there is a little bit of delta in the save files (which would explain it keeps getting bigger even when I am not doing much) then deactivating autosave may be worth while to keep the size down. Just remember that you have to save eventually and Skyrim does crash from time to time. Personally, I keep autosave on.

The 2.01 update improved the situation, but not completely. When lag becomes an issue for me, I just load up an old (small) save file and load back the current one.